# Copying the result of one div to a textarea-div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webspeech-api

I'm working on a system, which should have the option to be be controlled via speech using the Webspeech API.
My problem or question is: How do I copy the result of the voice recognition (which is stored in the "transcript-div") to the "usercomment textarea-div". Like the user says something and the recognized string should be copied to the usercomment automatically.

The corresponding lines of code:
The voice Recognizer:

```
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    var final_transcript = '';
    var interim_transcript = '';
    var language = 'en-GB'; 

    recognition.continuous = true; // keep processing input until stopped
    recognition.interimResults = true; // show interim results
    recognition.lang = language; // specify the language

    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        // Assemble the transcript from the array of results
        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                final_transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
                interim_transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
        }

        console.log("interim: " + interim_transcript);
        console.log("final: " + final_transcript);

        // update the web page
        if (final_transcript.length > 0) {
            $('#transcript').html(final_transcript);
        }

        if (interim_transcript.length > 0) {
            $('#interim').html(interim_transcript);
        }
```

For debugging purpose I've created another div, which shows the recognized phrases. This is working!

```
<div id="console" style="margin-top: 100px;">  
<h3>Console:</h3>  
    <div id="transcript"></div>  
    <div id="interim"></div>  
</div>
```

And now the content of the "transcript-Div" should be copied to the usercomment-**textarea-Div**:

```
<div id="UsercommentDiv" style="margin-top: 100px;">  
    <br> User Comment :<br> <textarea id="usercomment" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" name="description" onLoad="fillUsercomment();"></textarea><br>
</div>
```

I've tried to do this by the following function:

```
function fillUsercomment(){
document.getElementById('usercomment').innerHTML = document.getElementById('transcript').innerHTML
}  
fillUsercomment();
```

The fillUsercomment function works (when I call the function manually, it pastes the content to the usercomment textarea. But how I have to change the code, to paste the recognized output on the fly in the textarea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `innerHTML` of the `div` and apply it as `value` to the `textarea` (<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/w7Dq2/)</kbd>):

```
var div = document.getElementById("transcript");
var txt = document.getElementById("usercomment");

txt.value = div.innerHTML;
```

Or jQuery way:

```
$("#usercomment").val($("#transcript").html());
```

---

### Edited

If `final_transcript` is the recognition result string you want to append, here:

> ```
> // update the web page
> if (final_transcript.length > 0) {
>     $('#transcript').html(final_transcript);
> }
> ```

you should append "final_transcript" to textarea's value:

```
var txt = $("#usercomment");
txt.val(txt.val() + final_transcript);
```

---

### Edited 2

Here is <kbd>[your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/a4WLB/2/)</kbd> (look on 17 and 18 lines of JavaScript).

You can read what is `val()` function does [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately I'm not smart enough (maybe because I'm not an experienced programmer and especially jquery is quite new for me). So...I don't know to include your suggestion into my code. Maybe you could have a look here. I've created this fiddle for a better overview: http://jsfiddle.net/a4WLB/

Comment: All you need is to append final recognition results to "usercomment" textarea?

Comment: Edited 2. Feel free to ask questions if it is unclear

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you very much. Just one question left. Is it somehow possible to map the functionality to a function or something like this? In general the user should have the option to fill also other input fields (like project description, project type...) by using his own voice. So basically it's about, depending on the current focus, the recognized output should be copied to the div. In your provided example the output is copied everytime to the usercomments-div. Thanks again!

Comment: Shortly, you can pass some textarea's or input's ID to some function, which will start the recognition; then use passed ID as in fiddle on line 17 instead of "#usercomment". [**Here**](http://stiltsoft.com/blog/2013/05/google-chrome-how-to-use-the-web-speech-api/) is good article about speech recognition.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into this. Probably I will have another question on weekend ;), but for now: Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **jQuery**

```
$("#usercomment").attr("value", $("#transcript").text() );
```

or

```
 $("#usercomment").val( $("#transcript").text() );
```

P.S. Sorry I misunderstood at first, I edited now.